# How should we understand the connection between the Prophet and the poem of Tarafa and what is the authenticity of the narration if there is any?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, source-identification, authenticity, poetry

In the known mu'allaqa of [Tarafa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarafa) the poet -whom in my opinion used many words of wisdom which seem to go along with many teachings of Islam- said/wrote the verse saying:

> ستُبْدي لكَ الأيامُ ما كنتَ جاهلاً * ويأتيكَ بالأخبارِ من لم تزوِّدِ

which I would translate:

> The days (the time) will show you what you didn't know about * * *
>   And you'll be given news from somebody you didn't tell any

Which I found [here](http://www.albany.edu/~joris/Tarafa.html) translated (maybe scattered) as follows:

> the days will lay * * * bare what you don't
>   yet know & * * * someone will refuse you bread
>   someone will come bringing news:

I found quotes (see below in Arabic) saying that this verse has a connection with Islam or maybe was used somehow by our Prophet () as it seems that ibn 'Abbas even said it is -like- the speech of *a* prophet

> وكان النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم يتمثل به ولا يقيم وزنه. وكان ابن عباس يقول أنه كلام نبي.

What is the authenticity and source of these? Especially as the Prophet AFAIK by Qur'an ([33:69](http://legacy.quran.com/36/69)) was not able to recite poetry!

Comment: Why was this down-voted?